# Find the volume of the solid that lies above the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2, z\geq0$, and below the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4z$

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid that lies above the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2, z\geq0$, and below the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4z$.

My attempt:

$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}+2$, then

$$\int\int_D(\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}+2)-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dA$$

Switching both surfaces to polar coordinates we have the cone given by $z=r$ and the sphere by $z=\sqrt{4-r^2}+2$

Solving we obtain $r=2$

So the region $D$ is a circle of radius $r=2$. Hence we can describe the region as

$$D=((r,\theta)|0\leq\theta\leq2\pi ,0\leq r\leq2)$$

So we compute:

$$Volume=\int\int_D(\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}+2)-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dA$$

$$=\int\int_D(\sqrt{4-r^2}+2-r)dA$$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 (r\sqrt{4-r^2}+2r-r^2)drd\theta$$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}4d\theta$$

$$=8\pi$$

Comment: For the intersection, you can use the fact that both the sphere and the cone have rotational symmetry around the $z$ axis. This means you can work out the intersection from the 2-D intersection of a circle and a line-pair in a single plane. E.g. in the $xz$ plane, the sphere projects to the circle $x^2 + (z-2)^2 = 4$ and the cone projects to $z = \pm x$. These intersect at $(\pm 2, 2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. Here I'll show how to visualize this as a body of revolution. It's always helpful to plot what you are looking for. The figure below shows a vertical cross-section on the $x-z$ plane for rotation of the shaded area about the $z$-axis.

First, the simple *geometric* solution,

$$V=V_{cone}+V_{hemisphere}=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h~+~\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=8\pi$$

since $r=h=2$.

Now, the *calculus* method. Using any of the standard methods for bodies of revolution (I prefer Pappus's theorem) we have in general for rotation about the $z$-axis that

$$V=\pi\int x^2~dz$$

which in this case amounts to

$$
\begin{align}
V
&=\pi\left[ \int_0^2 z^2~dz~+~\int_2^4(4z-z^2)~dz\right]\\
&=\pi\left[ \frac{z^3}{3}\biggr|_0^2~+~\left(2z^2- \frac{z^3}{3}\right)\biggr|_2^4\right]\\
&=8\pi
\end{align}
$$

[image: area for body of revolution]